# Using Identity in 2 dbcontext ASP.NET Core, EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 1.1 Project with EF Core in Visual Studio 2017.
I have an `ApplicationUser.cs` class and the corresponding `ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`.

Additionally, I have a `MyClass.cs` class containing `PersonA.cs` and `PersonB.cs` both deriving from a class `Person`.
Next to that I have a second dbcontext file: `MyClassBdContext`based on `MyClass`

My question is how can I use `Identity` for this second dbcontext.

In my website, a user can login consuming the `ApplicatioUser` class and should be additionally able to insert in the `MyClassDbContext` database an object of the class `PersonA` or `PersonB` taking over some of the login data. To be more precise: `PersonA` or `PersonB` could be the one who has loggedin.

My idea is to keep authentication and authorisation separated from my business-database.

Any help is appreciated

Regards